# Elasticsearch post_filter aggregate query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am interested in all APIs which have not returned even one 200 response (in a specific time interval).

I basically need this:

```
     select url from api_log
      except/minus 
     select url from api_log where status='200'
```

Translating to ES, I am trying an equivalent of this:

1. First calculate aggregates.

```
     select url, status, count(*) from api_log
     group by url, status
```

2. From the ensuing results, filter out all records which have children with status: 200

**ES Sample Data**

```
{
    "_index": "api_log",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "in_time": "2019-05-13T17:20:51.108945",
        "out_time": "2019-05-13T17:20:51.145549",
        "duration": 36.6041660308838,
        "status": "200",
        "url": "/api/myFirstAPI"
    }
}
,
{
    "_index": "api_log",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "in_time": "2019-05-13T17:20:57.915694",
        "out_time": "2019-05-13T17:20:57.941989",
        "duration": 26.2949466705322,
        "status": "403",
        "url": "/api/mySecondAPI"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "api_log",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "in_time": "2019-05-13T17:22:35.274372",
        "out_time": "2019-05-13T17:22:35.288944",
        "duration": 14.5719051361084,
        "status": "400",
        "url": "/api/myFirstAPI"
    }
}
```

For above data I want the result url as {'/api/mySecondAPI'}.

**Request/Response with just AGG**

```
POST /api_log/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "url": {
      "terms": {
    "field": "url.keyword"
      },
      "aggregations": {
    "status": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status.keyword"
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response for above request**

```
{
  "took" : 880,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "url" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 394668,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "/api/myFirstRequest",
          "doc_count" : 1352845,
          "status" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "200",
                "doc_count" : 1187611
              },
              {
                "key" : "302",
                "doc_count" : 139932
              },
              {
                "key" : "401",
                "doc_count" : 22615
              },
              {
                "key" : "500",
                "doc_count" : 2250
              },
              {
                "key" : "403",
                "doc_count" : 437
              }
            ]
          }
        },
...
...
...
```

From above I need to filter out all buckets (URLs) which DO NOT have sub-buckets with status: "200"

I have come this far. Looks quite close, yet very far....Can't seem to figure out what should be in the type field.

**Request with filter**

```
POST /api_log/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "page_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url.keyword"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "post_filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "has_child" : {
                    "type" : "?????",
                    "query" : {
                        "term" : {"status" : "200"}
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

**Sample Input (From apache log):**

```
t1 /api/FirstAPI 200  <-- Eliminate First API completely
t2 /api/FirstAPI 400
t3 /api/FirstAPI 403
t4 /api/SecondAPI 403
t5 /api/SecondAPI 400
t6 /api/ThirdAPI 500
t7 /api/ThirdAPI 500
t8 /api/SecondAPI 200   <---Eliminate Second API completely
t9 /api/ThirdAPI 500
t10 /api/ThirdAPI 403
```

Given above input I want only pages which have NEVER given 200 response in time frame t1-t10.

**Expected Result**

So, the output should be just
/api/ThirdAPI

If I just filter out 200 first and then apply Agg, I will get all three APIs. That's not what I want.

Comment: Can you add some sample api_log data and the mapping/schema?

Comment: Added more information as required by you @TheUknown

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to exclude 200 from the aggregation. I dont see a reason to use `post_filter` here. You can use the **terms aggregation**.

[Exclude or filter the status value in aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values). This will count all the `200` responses and add in the `doc_count` field but will exclude the buckets in the aggregation response and will not show `200`

```
POST /api_log/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "url": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url.keyword"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.keyword",
            "exclude": "200"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternative:**

Based on your input it looks like you want the `200` as part of results set(since you re using post_filter), but if not, here's another way if that was not the case. Aggregation is done on the query response; so if you use the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to exclude 200 from result set, you will not have any buckets with 200 status.

```
POST /api_log/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "status": [
                  "200"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "url": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "url.keyword"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "status": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "status.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortuantely that's not what I want. Pls see my question edited again. I have added sample data for more clarity @TheUknown